# What does it mean by @SpringBootConfiguration allows the configuration to be found automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I was searching for the difference between the @Configuration vs @SpringBootConfiguration. I found many articles mentioned "As per the Spring documentation, @SpringBootConfiguration is just an alternative to the Spring standard @Configuration annotation. The only difference between the two is that the @SpringBootConfiguration allows the configuration to be found automatically".

So what does it mean by @SpringBootConfiguration allows the configuration to be found automatically? If we use the @Configuration for a class that contains @Bean annotated methods, Spring will create instantiation for those beans as well. Can anybody explain this to me clearly?

Answer (score 2):

Because this question was driving me a little crazy and this was the first StackOverflow page I found, which didn't resolve the issue for me, I'm going to try to explain my findings:

- [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) is a specialisation of [@SpringBootConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html), which is a specialisation of @Configuration.
- You may only have 1 [@SpringBootConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html), which means you can't have both a [@SpringBootConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html) and a [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html) in your application.
- "[@SpringBootConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringBootConfiguration.html) allows the configuration to be found automatically" means you don't have to do anything to have this (and therefore [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)) found. Other @Configuration classes are generally discovered by @ComponentScan
- An extra advantage over @Configuration, is that it will be discovered by [@StringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just open https://github.dev/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/src/docs/asciidoc and search for **SpringBootConfiguration** you will find some information about it.
such as

> @SpringBootConfiguration: enable registration of extra beans in the
> context or the import of additional configuration classes. An
> alternative to Spring’s standard @Configuration that aids
> **configuration detection** in your integration tests.

and

> **Detecting Test Configuration** If you are familiar with the Spring Test
> Framework, you may be used to using @ContextConfiguration(classes=…​)
> in order to specify which Spring @Configuration to load.
> Alternatively, you might have often used nested @Configuration classes
> within your test.
>
> When testing Spring Boot applications, this is often not required.
> Spring Boot’s @*Test annotations search for your primary configuration
> automatically whenever you do not explicitly define one.
>
> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test
> until it finds a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication or
> @SpringBootConfiguration. As long as you structured your code in a
> sensible way, your main configuration is usually found.